# DDL commands are AutoCommit in SQL server, what does it mean?

Tags: sql-server

at most pages I have read that "DDL commands have AutoCommit in SQL Server", if I am not wrong this statement simply means that we don't need explicit commit command for DDL commands.

then why...

1) Alter TABLE EMP Add Age INT;
UPDATE EMP SET Age=20;

fails ,saying Invalid column name 'Age'

2) BEGIN TRAN
 Alter TABLE EMP Add Age INT;
ROLLBACK

can be rollbacked successfully.

Maybe I am wrong with concept of AutoCommit, please explain it with example where it actully has effects.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your first example shows that batches are compiled entirely before being executed. It has nothing to do with "autocommit" - and what resources are you referencing that make this statement?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, k then my first example is related with batches, sorry I was relating it with AutoCommit. But can you let me understand  "DDL commands are AutoCommit" with some example, what does it actually means?

Comment: I don't know where you got the phrase "DDL commands are AutoCommit" from - it doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me, since Autocommit is a transaction mode (compared with Implicit and Explicit transactions).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Autocommit Transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187878%28v=sql.105%29):

> A connection to an instance of the Database Engine operates in autocommit mode until a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` statement starts...

So, your second example doesn't apply. Further down:

> In autocommit mode, it sometimes appears as if an instance of the Database Engine has rolled back an entire batch instead of just one SQL statement. This happens if the error encountered is a compile error, not a run-time error. A compile error prevents the Database Engine from building an execution plan, so nothing in the batch is executed.

Which is what your first example deals with.

So, neither one is actually dealing with Autocommit transactions.

---

So, lets take a statement like:

```
Alter TABLE EMP Add Age INT;
```

If you have an open connection in Autocommit mode, execute the above, and it completes without errors, then you will find that this connection has no open transactions, and the changes are visible to any other connection immediately.

If you have an open connection in Implicit Transactions mode, execute the above, and it completes without errors, then you will find that this connection has an open transaction. Other connections will be blocked on any operations that require a schema lock on `EMP`, until you execute either `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`.

If you have an open connection, in which you have executed `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, execute the above, and it completes without errors - then you'll be in the same situation as for Implicit Transactions. However, having `COMMIT`ed or `ROLLBACK`ed, your connection will revert to either Autocommit mode or Implicit Transactions mode (whichever was active before the call to `BEGIN TRANSACTION`).

Comment: thnx, @Damien_The_Unbeliever this answers clears a lot of my concept. I think "DDL commands are AutoCommit" concept is in Oracle and i was getting confuse by mixing it with SQL Server. Now can please tell me that is there any diff between DDL and DML related to transaction,commit,rollback...

Comment: @user369182 - none spring to mind. The page on [Implicit Transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188317(v=sql.105).aspx) has a list of the statements that are affected by the choice of mode.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, can I ask that you integrate your comments into your answer?  ie, lead off with "DDL has nothing to do with autocommit in sql server'.  The problem here is that transactions are explicit in oracle by default and DDL DOES 'autocommit' those explicit transactions.  So somebody looking to see if that is also true in sql server finds this answer, and at first glance believes it to be true.  Either that or we modify the question to "what is autocommit in sql server"

Answer (score 1):

If you have a begin tran explicitly like in your second example, then you have to commit it. (you can roll back as well)

If you dont specify it explicity like in your first example then it is autocommit.

autocommit is the default mode in sql server, which can be turned off if requried

Answer (score 0):

If you add batch in your code it will work

```
Alter TABLE EMP Add Age INT;
go
UPDATE EMP SET Age=20;
```