# Alter and update statement executed together

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update

This query has made my day bad.

It works when executed seperately one after other but creates error when the entire query is selected and executed.

```
ALTER TABLE ProcedureMaster
add TierId smallint null

update ProcedureMaster set TierId=3 where TierId is null
```

The error is :

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid column name 'TierId'.
```

Comment: Please do go through this: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390745/ddl-commands-are-autocommit-in-sql-server-what-does-it-mean`. The answer applies to your question.

Comment: @Abhi why is your link `code` instead of [a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390745/ddl-commands-are-autocommit-in-sql-‌​server-what-does-it-mean)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alter like this using GO:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
ALTER TABLE ProcedureMaster
add TierId smallint null
GO
update ProcedureMaster set TierId=3 where TierId is null   
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: but I do not want to add a default. I want that when this new column is added it just updates old record with value 3 and then I would like to alter column to NOT NULL

Comment: @RahulRanjan:- I have removed the default statement. Please check teh updated answer!!